# Configuration panel videotron

Tags: privacy, internet

At the moment I am living in an apartment with some other people. We are students and we will start school in Canada.

One guy took internet with Videotron, he manages the internet and we just give him money for the bill. I wanted to know with the box and the configuration panel of the box, if he could see what I am doing on internet like password or something else.

I know that you can set your network as home or not but after I don't know if I have some other risk. I could use VPN but if with the configuration panel he can see information it's still bad.

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/a/30264/10885

Comment: Welcome to security.stackexchange.com. This question is (likely) going to be closed as a duplicate. If you read the duplicate questions and their answers and still have questions, ask a new question here, mention what you read and what questions you still have. I added one possible duplicate in a comment above though other users may have a better question to point you to.

Comment: Oh. A VPN will protect all network traffic that is sent over it, whether you're using HTTP or HTTPS, from the router's admin. All the admin will be able to see is that you're using a VPN and which VPN provider you are using. I like https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/ though YMMV.