# Has my browser been hacked, there was a tab I didn’t open editing my LinkedIn profile

Tags: web-browser

Is it possible that somebody could have access to my web browser through wifi hacking and edited my LinkedIn profile (or any other social media if it’s open)? There was a tab that mysteriously opened after I was away from the computer which didn’t have the secure lock symbol that always shows on LinkedIn but instead it was being directed through google drive? There’s no way I intentionally opened LinkedIn at that point of time.

I can attach screenshots, sorry if this doesn’t make sense. Is it at all possible that an attacker can hijack my browser if it’s been compromised? Especially if they’ve gotten in through my wifi, eg a neighbour? What can be done? I’ve changed all my passwords and am only using my mobile phone for internet at the moment. I know it sounds paranoid but I don’t know too much about this.

[If someone hacks my wi-fi password, what can they see and how?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30261/if-someone-hacks-my-wi-fi-password-what-can-they-see-and-how)

Answer (score 1):

Hacking/obtaining access to WiFi is not enough to get into your computer/browser. It is likely your computer have been taken over using something like [RDP](https://www.lifewire.com/disable-windows-remote-desktop-153337) or TeamViewer. I recommend disabling RDP and uninstalling TeamViewer. If you need the functionality, you should check more secure alternatives.

Another possibility is, that you have some sort of malware in your PC. You can not go wrong by using few tools to scan your PC. I recommend Malware-bytes at the very least.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any possibility the computer can be taken over remotely even if I never gave the person access intentionally? Malware would be more than enough I assume to achieve this?

Comment: @546456456 Yes, malware is one way to do it. RDP passwords are considered weak and can therefore probably be broken. TeamViewer default passwords are also not the strongest and if you don't update TeamViewer (forgotten installation), it may contain vulnerabilities as well.